# How to style json feed output

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-mobile

I would like to style json feed output. I want to be able to arrange it as I want. So far this is my javascript code. I would like to achieve something like this [IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVgjV.jpg), information's such as age number etc would be possible to change location etc. I want this to work on jquery mobile as i am building an application.

```js
function listPosts(data) {
  var output = '<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">';



  $.each(data.posts, function(key, val)
  {


    var tempDiv = document.createElement("tempDiv");
    tempDiv.innerHTML = val.excerpt;
    $("a", tempDiv).remove();
    var excerpt = tempDiv.innerHTML;

    output += '<li>';
    output += '<a href="#blogpost" onclick = "showPost('+ val.id +') ">';
    output += '<h3>' + val.title + "</h3>";
    output += (val.thumbnail) ?
      '<img src="' + val.thumbnail + '" alt="' + val.title + '">':
      '<img src="images/itblogo.png" alt="ITB Logo">';
    output += '<h3>' +  val.custom_fields.gender + "</h3>";
    output += '<h3>' +  val.custom_fields.age + "</h3>";

    output += '</a>';
    output += '</li>';



  }); //go through each post
  output += "</ul>";
  $('#postlist').html(output);
} //listPosts








function showPost(id) {
  $.getJSON('http://www.pawmatch.info?json=get_post&post_id=' + id + '&callback=?', function(data) {
    var
    output ='<img src="'+data.post.thumbnail + '">'
    output += '<h3>' + data.post.custom_fields.dogs_name + '</h3>'
    output +='<h3>'+data.post.custom_fields.dog_size + '</h3>'
    output +='<h3>'+data.post.custom_fields.age + '</h3>'
    output +='<h3>'+data.post.custom_fields.gender + '</h3>'
    output +='<h3>'+data.post.custom_fields.breed + '</h3>'
    output +='<h3>'+data.post.custom_fields.extra_information + '</h3>'
    $('#mypost').html(output);
  });
}
```

Comment: What's the issue. Getting any errors?

Comment: No errors, is just that i would like to arrange it like you can style html in css, i would like to do the same in that feed. because it only shows the information but it shows them in the wrong place etc.

Comment: Take a look at ES2016's template strings. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Or if you are using ECMAScript 5 I suggest using Handlebars for this.
http://handlebarsjs.com/